# Elasticsearch arithmetic and nested aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I've this kind of objects in my ElasticSearch:

```
"myobject": {
  "type": "blah",
   "events": [
    {
      "code": "code1"
      "date": "2016-08-03 18:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "code2"
      "date": "2016-08-03 20:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to compute the average time spend in between events with code "code1" and events with type "code2". Basically, I need to subtract the date of "code2" from the date of "code1" for each object and then compute the average.

thanks for you help !

Comment: This will not work as easy as you might think. You either need "events" to be nested and then you would need some script aggregations which I am not even sure you can do... Can you index the 2 events separate and not in an array?

Comment: Hi @DennisIch, "events" array is declared as a nested array in my mapping. I'm currently looking what I can do with script metric aggregation ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html ). I could subtract in the map phase, and then do the average on the reduce phase. As a B plan I could pre compute the date diff with a script on insert/update.

Comment: Ok, this works well but takes too much time when data is growing. So the right solution is to pre-compute these values @Val suggests bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan B is definitely MUCH better. Anything you can do at indexing time, you should do. If you know you'll need that date difference, then you should compute it at indexing time and store it into another field.

You should definitely **not worry about storing redundant data**, Elasticsearch doesn't really care. Your cluster will be much better off storing a few more fields than doing heavy scripting during each query. Your users will appreciate, too, as they won't have to wait for ages to get an answer as your data grows.

So store this instead (`time_spent` is the number of milliseconds between the second and the first event):

```
"myobject": {
  "type": "blah",
   "time_spent": 7200000,
   "events": [
    {
      "code": "code1"
      "date": "2016-08-03 18:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "code2"
      "date": "2016-08-03 20:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you'll be able to run a simple aggregation query like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "avg_duration": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "time_spent"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although it is a little bit of a constraint to pre-compute these values on insertion I think it is the right way to go when dealing with lots of data. Map/Reduce scripting can work only on small datasets.

Comment: You should not be afraid to duplicate the data at indexing time so as to make it easier to crunch it at search/aggregation time. You need to adopt a different mindset than with RDBMS.

Comment: Val I've no problem with duplicating the data particularly when I excatly know how the data will be queried. The issue here is that I don't exactly know in advance all the queries (BI) which may lead to pre-compute new values for the all data if a new query is necessary.